# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl() returns null for Google user with profile picture on Emulators

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, google-account

I'm using Firebase UI to sign-in the users of my app. When a Google user signs in, I would like to retrieve the profile picture (for use in my GUI). However, for all Google users the method `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl()` returns `null`.

Note that I'm setting the default Scope in the setup of Firebase-UI.

I'm sure that the Google accounts have a profile picture (it's even visible in dialog that appears after clicking the the "Sign in with Google" button).

Code in which I configure Firebase-UI:

```
startActivityForResult( AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setTheme( R.style.AppTheme )
                        .setLogo( R.drawable.app_logo )
                        .setTosUrl(getSelectedTosUrl() )
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled( false )
                        .setAvailableProviders( Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().setRequireName( false ).build())
                        ).build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Code in which I try to retrieve the account image:

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null){
  Log.d(TAG, "Account image: user has a photoUrl: " + user.getPhotoUrl());
}
```

`getPhotoUrl()` always returns null.

Comment: seems unusual error. Did you confirm that user is not null?

Comment: @MayurDusane yes, I am sure that user is not null, I can retrieve all other fields such as displayname, mail, providerId etc.

Comment: Note that I'm encountering this only on emulators, not on real devices...